# Jetpack Compose BackHandler doesn't trigger on my Android 9 phone

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using compose navigation in my app. I have 2 screens - pressing button on screen 1 navigates me to screen 2 and pressing the (system) back button navigates me back to screen 1. That's how it works on my Android 14 phone. I want this to also work on older phones, so I tested this interaction on my Android 9 phone. I can go from screen 1 to screen 2 without any problems, but I can't go back - the back button doesnt do anything.

I added BackHandler to my composable and tried debugging. The results are that on A14 the BackHandler gets triggered a executes the code inside, but it doesn't trigger on my A9 phone.

```
var number by remember { mutableIntStateOf(1) }

BackHandler(enabled = true) {
    number++
}
Text(number.toString())
```

Pressing the back button increments the number on A14 phone, but not on the older one.